# Problem splitting a linked list into two other linked lists in c

Tags: c, linked-list

My code is supposed stores 10 int numbers in a linked list, divide these 10 numbers equally into two other linked lists. But my two lists are returning empty

My struct:

```
typedef struct no
{
    int value;
    struct no *next;
} no;
```

The variable size comes from a function that loops through my main list and returns its size.
Then created two "almost equal" functions to take the value from the main list and store it in the ListB and ListC.

My functions:

```
no* copylist(no *list, no *listReceive,int size)
{
    no *aux = list;
    no *receive=listReceive;

    int count=0;


    while(aux!=NULL&&count<size/2)
    {
        insert(receive, aux->value);

        aux=aux->next;
    }
    count = size/2;


    return receive;
}
no* copylist1(no *list, no *listReceive,int size)
{
    no *aux = list;
    no *receive=listReceive;

    int count=0;

    while(aux!=NULL&&count<size/2)
    {
        aux=aux->next;
        count++;
    }

    count = size/2;
    aux=aux->next;

    while(aux!=NULL&&count<size)
    {
        insert(receive, aux->value);

        aux=aux->next;
    }


    return receive;
}
```

Obs: for me linked lists is a very confusing content

Comment: Your `insert` call does not make any sense -- you seem to be confused about parameter passing.  In C function parameters are always passed *by value*, so the function has *a copy* of the caller's value.  Changes to the parameter in the function do not affect variables in the caller, unless you explicitly pass an address with `&`

Comment: *[Not offering any solutions but...]* Your approach seems to be creating another lists (containing half of the original list) - this process in my opinion is slow, use two pointers (one going `node->next` and other going `node->next->next` i.e. at double speed) to find the mid of the list & then just reassign the `head` - so you won't need to copy the entire list.

Comment: You will help yourself and others if you format your code for better readability, e.g. instead of `while(aux!=NULL&&count<size)` write `while (aux != NULL && count < size)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The split can be done in a *single* pass if we use *two* pointers. One that traverses via `cur1 = cur1->next` and another that traverses twice as fast (e.g. `cur2 = cur2->next->next`);

When `cur2` reaches the end, `cur1` will be at the midpoint.

When we pass a "single star" pointer that is the list start to a function that must adjust and return the head of the list, the adjustment will *not* be reflected back to the *caller*.

Rather than pass down "double star" pointers for this lists, it's easier/better to use a separate list `struct` in addition to the node `struct`.

Note that we *could* co-opt/reuse a [dummy] node as the list pointer, but it's more clear if we use the separate struct.

Below is some annotated code. Unfortunately, I had to refactor a good deal of it to get it to work.

---

Here is a version that does [depending on the program argument]:

1. A simple *two* pass version. One to compute the count and a second pass to do the split based on that count
2. An improved version that does the split in a *single* pass by using the "two pointer" technique mentioned above

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int passno;

// node
typedef struct no {
    int value;
    struct no *next;
} no;

// list
typedef struct li {
    no *head;
} li;

// show -- show a list
void
show(li *lst,const char *sym)
{

    printf("%s:",sym);

    for (no *cur = lst->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        printf(" %2d",cur->value);

    printf("\n");
}

// newlist -- create a new list with N elements
li *
newlist(int count)
{
    li *lst = malloc(sizeof(*lst));
    no *cur;
    no *prev;

    lst->head = NULL;

    prev = NULL;
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < count;  ++idx) {
        cur = malloc(sizeof(*cur));
        cur->next = NULL;

        cur->value = idx + 1;

        if (prev != NULL)
            prev->next = cur;
        else
            lst->head = cur;

        prev = cur;
    }

    return lst;
}

// lstcount -- count number of elements in the list
int
lstcount(li *lst)
{
    no *cur;
    int count = 0;

    for (cur = lst->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        ++count;

    return count;
}

// splitA -- split a list into two halves (single pointer, two pass version)
void
splitA(li *lstleft,li *lstright,li *lstfrom)
{
    int count;
    int idx;
    no *cur;
    no *left;

    count = lstcount(lstfrom);
    count = (count + 1) / 2;

    left = NULL;
    lstleft->head = NULL;

    idx = 0;
    for (cur = lstfrom->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        if (++idx > count)
            break;

        // append to left list
        if (left == NULL)
            lstleft->head = cur;

        left = cur;
    }

    // disconnect/cut the tail of the left list from the right list
    if (left != NULL)
        left->next = NULL;

    // start the right list
    lstright->head = cur;

    // zap the original list
    lstfrom->head = NULL;
}

// splitB -- split a list into two halves (two pointer, one pass version)
void
splitB(li *lstleft,li *lstright,li *lstfrom)
{
    no *cur1;
    no *cur2;
    no *left;

    left = NULL;
    lstleft->head = NULL;

    cur2 = lstfrom->head;
    for (cur1 = lstfrom->head;  cur1 != NULL;  cur1 = cur1->next) {
        // wait for double speed pointer to end
        if (cur2 == NULL)
            break;
        cur2 = cur2->next;

        // append to left list
        if (left == NULL)
            lstleft->head = cur1;
        left = cur1;

        // advance at twice the rate
        if (cur2 != NULL)
            cur2 = cur2->next;
    }

    // disconnect/cut the tail of the left list from the right list
    if (left != NULL)
        left->next = NULL;

    // start the right list
    lstright->head = cur1;

    // zap the original list
    lstfrom->head = NULL;
}

// clean -- free up list elements and list descriptor
void
clean(li *lst)
{
    no *cur;
    no *next;

    for (cur = lst->head;  cur != NULL;  cur = next) {
        next = cur->next;
        free(cur);
    }

    free(lst);
}

// dotest -- test the split for a given number of nodes
void
dotest(int count)
{
    li *big;
    li *left;
    li *right;

    printf("\n");
    printf("dotest: count=%d\n",count);

    big = newlist(count);
    show(big,"big");

    left = newlist(0);
    right = newlist(0);

    switch (passno) {
    case 1:
        splitA(left,right,big);
        break;
    case 2:
        splitB(left,right,big);
        break;
    }

    show(left,"lhs");
    show(right,"rhs");

    clean(left);
    clean(right);
    clean(big);
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc > 0)
        passno = atoi(*argv);
    if (passno <= 0)
        passno = 1;
    if (passno > 2)
        passno = 2;
    printf("passno=%d\n",passno);

    for (int count = 0;  count <= 12;  ++count)
        dotest(count);
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
passno=1

dotest: count=0
big:
lhs:
rhs:

dotest: count=1
big:  1
lhs:  1
rhs:

dotest: count=2
big:  1  2
lhs:  1
rhs:  2

dotest: count=3
big:  1  2  3
lhs:  1  2
rhs:  3

dotest: count=4
big:  1  2  3  4
lhs:  1  2
rhs:  3  4

dotest: count=5
big:  1  2  3  4  5
lhs:  1  2  3
rhs:  4  5

dotest: count=6
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6
lhs:  1  2  3
rhs:  4  5  6

dotest: count=7
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
lhs:  1  2  3  4
rhs:  5  6  7

dotest: count=8
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8
lhs:  1  2  3  4
rhs:  5  6  7  8

dotest: count=9
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
lhs:  1  2  3  4  5
rhs:  6  7  8  9

dotest: count=10
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
lhs:  1  2  3  4  5
rhs:  6  7  8  9 10

dotest: count=11
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
lhs:  1  2  3  4  5  6
rhs:  7  8  9 10 11

dotest: count=12
big:  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
lhs:  1  2  3  4  5  6
rhs:  7  8  9 10 11 12
```